# How to transfer the password (PIN) in the form at the signature by means of the certificate which is on a flash drive?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, code-signing

I need to sign a lot of documents and this code works. The problem is that every time I see the form for entering the password.
How to transfer the password (PIN) in the form at the signature by means of the certificate which is on a flash drive?

INFO: can't export the private key from a flash drive (the key market is not exported)

```
static public byte[] SignToken(Byte[] tokenToSignBytes, X509Certificate2 signerCert)
{
    //  Place message in a ContentInfo object.
    //  This is required to build a SignedCms object.
    ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(tokenToSignBytes);

    //  Instantiate SignedCms object with the ContentInfo above.
    //  Has default SubjectIdentifierType IssuerAndSerialNumber.
    //  Has default Detached property value false, so message is
    //  included in the encoded SignedCms.
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

    //  Formulate a CmsSigner object for the signer.
    CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);
    Console.WriteLine(cmsSigner);

    //  Sign the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
    Console.Write("Computing signature with signer subject name {0} ... ", signerCert.SubjectName.Name);
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
    //signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, true); // it's not working
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");

    //  Encode the CMS/PKCS #7 message.
    return signedCms.Encode();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the PIN, I would refactor the code to define `cmsSigner` variable outside and only once. Then pass this parameter to `SignToken` method. Then you will be prompted for PIN only once when access the `cmsSigner` variable for the first time. Then you reuse the instance and no prompts should appear when you call `SignToken` method multiple times using same `cmsSigner` instance.

Comment: Okay, I'll try. thank you